Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\left[1+\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)\,dt\right]^{1/x^4}$, given $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$
The problem states that suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$, evaluate the limit below
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[1+\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)\,dt\right]^{1/x^4}$$
My thoughts on this problem are taking the logarithm of the limit function. Then use the ordinary tricks for handling the limit of functions. Let $g(x)$ denote the limit function. I got stuck in this step below:
\begin{align}
    \lim\limits_{x\to o} \ln g(x)&=
    \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt)}{x^4}\\
    &=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}
\end{align}
Then I used the  condition $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$, replacing $f(x^2-t^2)$ with $x^2-t^2$.Problem solved. But I don't get the mechanism or the theorems that allow me to do it. This integral $\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt$ looks very strange. It's not like the integrals depending on a parameter that takes the form $\int\limits_a^b F(t,x) dt$ which we have general theorems to approach  .So can someone explain the intricacy between these two integrals and the reason behind the substitute I made.

Not a solution but a comment on where you seem to be stuck. Separate out the "different" $x$'s in the integral. ie look at $F(u,v)=\int_{0}^{u} tf(v^2-t^2)dt$, where $u=x$, $v=x$: you can then use the chain rule to get the derivative w.r.t $x$ of  $\int_{0}^{u} tf(x^2-t^2)dt$ to use a L'HR type argument. But as I can't understand your previous line ....

You may substitute $t=xu$ in integral to simplify the limit expression as $\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^1 u f(x^2(1-u^2)),du$. Since the expression is even in $x$ you may just consider $x\to 0^+$ and apply the $\epsilon, \delta$ limit definition with $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)/x=1$.

Follow the OP's idea:
$$\begin{align}
    \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \ln g(x)&=
    \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt)}{x^4}\\
    &=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}
\end{align}.$$
Now we deal with the integral in the numerator: ($u=x^2-t^2$)
$$\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt
=\frac{-1}{2}\int_0^xf(x^2-t^2)d(x^2-t^2)
=\frac12\int^{x^2}_{0}f(u)d u.$$
So we can get by L'Hospital rule:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int^{x^2}_{0}f(u)d u}{2x^4}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2xf(x^2)}{8x^3}
=\frac14\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x^2)}{(x^2)^2}
=\frac14.$$
Hence
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[1+\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)\,dt\right]^{1/x^4}
=e^{1/4}.$$

This is very helpful! Your treatment of the numerator is great, thanks. Weirdly, I accidentally get the same answer just by substituting  $f(x^2-t^2)$ with $x^2-t^2$

Glad to help you!

Pretty much exactly what was suggested in the comments. We can rewright the integral as $\int_0^{|x|} tf(x^2-t^2)dt$ for if we allow $x<0$, the substitution $t=-y$ gives $\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt=\int_0^{|x|} yf(x^2-y^2)dy$.
Given $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently small $|x|$, $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}-1\right|<\epsilon$. So,
$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\int_0^{|x|} tf(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}-\frac{\int_0^{|x|} t(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}\right|&=\left|\int_0^{|x|}\frac{ t(x^2-t^2)}{x^4}\left(\frac{f(x^2-t^2)}{x^2-t^2}-1\right)dt\right|\\&\leq\int_0^{|x|}\left|\frac{ t(x^2-t^2)}{x^4}\right|\left|\frac{f(x^2-t^2)}{x^2-t^2}-1\right|dt\\&<\int_0^{|x|}\epsilon\frac{t(x^2-t^2)}{x^4} dt=\frac{\epsilon}{4}
\end{align}$
This shows that $\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{\int_0^{|x|} tf(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}-\frac{\int_0^{|x|} t(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}\right)=0$, hence $\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\int_0^{|x|} tf(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}&=\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{\int_0^{|x|} tf(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}-\frac{\int_0^{|x|} t(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}\right)+\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\int_0^{|x|} t(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_0^{|x|} t(x^2-t^2)dt}{x^4}\end{align}$
